# Xcode Tip: finding wrong-formatted strings in localization files

Tags: ios, xcode

When editing localization string files [e.g. Localizable.strings (English)] in Xcode, you will frequently fall into a problem that the compilation fails with wrongly formatted lines, but Xcode doesn't show where is the problem.

I have found a simple method for locating such lines, and am going to share it in my answer here...

Answer (score 1):

The following method can be used to find the wrongly formatted lines:

search for `"[^"]*" = "[^"]*";`

Xcode is using RegEx search. The above phrase means to search for lines 
with a `"` followed by zero-or-more `non-"` followed by `" = "` followed by zero-or-more `non-"` followed by `";`

When activating such search, Xcode will mark all correct lines with yellow, leaving the wrong lines untouched, as in:

[image]